# :root selector is not working in the Angular component

Tags: css, angular

I'd like to try to use css variables in my Angular 11 component.

```html
<div class="main-content">
  <a>Test Link</a>
</div>
```

With this `app.component.css`

```css
div.main-content{
  --main-color: red
}

a{
  color: var(--main-color);
}
```

But if I try to use `:root` in my css link is black.

```css
:root {
  --main-color: red
}

a{
  color: var(--main-color);
}
```

> The :root selector matches the document's root element.

Why it doesn't match in my case?

**UPDATE** If I put `:root` to default `styles.css` in angular project that is included globally everything works.
What's wrong with my `app.component.css`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't use the `:root` selector in an Angular component, it just simply won't work, neither should it. Check out https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/32177.

Answer (score 4):

You can use :host selector at component level to define css variables and it works.

```
:host {
  --circle-size: clamp(1.5rem, 5vw, 4rem);
  --spacing: clamp(0.25rem, 2vw, 0.5rem);
  --main-color: red;
}
```

see https://angular.io/guide/component-styles for more details

Answer (score 0):

you can do this. Maybe not best practice but it works. Also in Angular 16 which I am currently using

```
::ng-deep your-component {

}
```